# Como implementar una funcion para pasarle char array para el esp8266

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266, cliente

Estoy tratndo de implementar un sketch usando un `esp8266 como servidor`, necesito enviar una cadena de caracteres al cliente y para ello estoy usando esta pieza de codigo:

```
  char sbuf[] = "Hello world!\n\r";
  size_t len = strlen(sbuf);
  for (i = 0; i < MAXCLIENTS; i++) {
  if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected()) {
    serverClients[i].write((char*) &sbuf, len);
    delay(1);
  }
}
```

Todo `funciona OK` y el cliente puede recibir los caracteres, ahora quiero hacer `una funcion` de esto para poder llamarlo cuando lo necesito, asi he tratado de implementar mi funcion:

```
void sendDataToClient( char *sbuf[]) {
size_t len = strlen(sbuf) + 1;
for (i = 0; i < MAXCLIENTS; i++) {
 if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected()) {
   serverClients[i].write((char*) &sbuf, len);
   delay(1);
  }
 }
}
```

y asi estoy `llamando a la funcion`:

```
char bufferMSGtoClient[] = "Hello world!\n\r\0";

sendDataToClient(bufferMSGtoClient);
```

Pero esto `no funcion`, el cliente no recibe nada, alguien me podria decir cual es mi `error?`

Comment: Por favor, no actualizes la pregunta con las correcciones de una respuesta, ya que eso invalida la respuesta. Hice una edición para volverla al estado original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando declaras una función con un arreglo como parámetro, en realidad la función
recibe un puntero al primer elemento del arreglo. En este caso:

```
void sendDataToClient(char sbuf[]);
```

Es equivalente a:

```
void sendDataToClient(char *sbuf);
```

Luego al obtener el tamaño de `sbuf` con `sizeof` obtienes 4 (el tamaño de un
`char *` en tu sistema) y no el tamaño del arreglo.

Puedes arreglarlo pasando explicitamente el tamaño al llamar la función, por
ejemplo:

```
void sendDataToClient(char sbuf[], size_t len) {
    // ...
}

int main(void) {
    char bufferMSGtoClient[] = "Hello World!\n\r";

    sendDataToClient(bufferMSGtoClient, sizeof bufferMSGtoClient);
}
```

Si no quieres pasar el tamaño como segundo argumento tienes dos opciones:

- Definir un macro que use sizeof sobre su argumento y tener cuidado de no
  pasarle expresiones que tengan efectos secundarios:

```
#define SEND_DATA_TO_CLIENT(sbuf) sendDataToClient(sbuf, sizeof sbuf)
```

- Si solo vas a mandar cadenas (terminadas en '\0') y no te importa la perdida
  de eficiencia, puedes usar `strlen` para calcular el tamaño de forma dinámica:

```
void sendDataToClient(char sbuf[]) {
    size_t len = strlen(sbuf) + 1;
    // ...
}
```

---

Hay otro error en esta parte:

```
serverClients[i].write((char*) &sbuf, len);
```

`sbuf` dentro de la función es un puntero a char (`char *`) asi que puedes pasarlo
directamente sin castearlo, quedando así:

```
serverClients[i].write(sbuf, len);
```

la forma que usas no funciona porque estas tomando la dirección en memoria de
`sbuf` con el operador *&*, pero `sbuf` ya es una dirección en memoria (un puntero)
así que el resultado que obtienes de `&sbuf` es un `char **` (puntero a puntero a char).

Comment: braver, lo he hecho como tu lo estas sugeriendo, ya tengo el numero de caracteres correcto pero el cliente no logra recibir nada

Comment: Se me pasó por alto un detalle, ahora en un rato actualizo la respuesta.